# How to make video controls not auto-hide in IE?

Tags: html, html5-video

I'm using a  tag to play an audio file so that browsers would not ignore the  tag because I want to display closed captions for my audio using the oncuechange event.

The problem is that in IE, the default video player auto-hides it's controls after a while and only appears when hovered on.

This is a problem because by the time the user scrolls down, the controls would disappear and the user would not be aware that there is a media player there.

Is there a way to make it so that the controls would not auto-hide?

Anyway, I'm hoping to avoid using a wrapper player if possible.

Comment: The easiest is probably to use a ["poster"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-poster) attribute with an icon indicating the presence of a player here. A more hackish solution would be to listen to scroll events on the page and trigger the videoElement's `focus` method. It seems IE does show the controls then.